# How to return only the wanted vector in the which() funtion

Tags: r, indexing

I have this initial matrix:

```
> fil
2 3 6 
1 1 1

> str(fil)
 Named num [1:3] 1 1 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "2" "3" "6"
```

When I do this:

```
which(fil==min(fil,na.rm = TRUE))
```

I have this returned

```
> which(fil==min(fil,na.rm = TRUE))
2 3 6 
1 2 3
```

And I wanted the names of the vector to be returned:

```
2 3 6
```

Comment: What is `ii` in your code? Is this inside a for loop or something? Can you please show the complete code your are using?

Comment: Also, please explain the logic. `which` gives the index, but you want the value? And what does `min` have to do with it? It seems like maybe you want the max of each column??

Comment: If `fil` is a named vector, then you want to do your `which` on the `names(fil)`

Comment: it appears you want to filter out the `min` values, not get the `min`. So you're missing a `!` in front of your logical. also, if you want the values you would use `fil[!fil==min(fil,na.rm=TRUE)]`, not `which` [edit: or maybe fil is a named vector as per @Sotos comment?]

Comment: It is named, just edited to show that

Comment: You want the `names(fill)[which(etc)]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Would you mind formulating your answer, it actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see an output like the one in the question, you must suspect that the upper vector are the *names* of the vector printed below them. What is below is the actual vector, its values, not the first line of the output.
This is confirmed with `str`

```
str(fil)
# Named num [1:3] 1 1 1
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "2" "3" "6"
```

It starts by saying `Named num`, so it is a *named numeric* vector.
Then there is an `attributes` line. The attribute in question is `"names"`. And there are functions to get some frequent attributes, such as the `"names"` attribute.

```
fil <- c('2' = 1, '3' = 1, '6' = 1)

fil
#2 3 6 
#1 1 1

attributes(fil)
#$names
#[1] "2" "3" "6"
```

There are two ways to get the attribute `"names"`. The second is the shorcut I will use:

```
attr(fil, "names")
#[1] "2" "3" "6"

names(fil)
#[1] "2" "3" "6"
```

Now, to answer the question, just subset the names that correspond to the minimum of the vector `fil`.

```
names(fil)[which(fil==min(fil,na.rm = TRUE))]
#[1] "2" "3" "6"
```